# Keras error - "we expect the tensors to have a static batch size"

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, deep-learning

I am trying a multi-input model but getting and error. Here is my code:

```
### Features
toks_pad = pad_sequences(toks_feat, maxlen=maxlen, dtype  = 'object', value= None)
pos_pad  = pad_sequences(pos_feat,  maxlen=maxlen, dtype  = 'object', value= None)
print(f"toks_pad shape:{toks_pad.shape} | pos_pad shape {pos_pad.shape}")
```

> toks_pad shape:(143, 15) | pos_pad shape (143, 15)

```
toks_pad[0]
```

> array([None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None,
>          'hearing loss', 'of', 'causes', 'are', 'impaction', 'presbyacusis'],
>         dtype=object)

```
print(f"ntoks:{ntoks} | npos:{npos} | ndep:{ndep} | nrel:{nrel} | maxlen:{maxlen}")
toks_inp   = Input(shape=(maxlen,), dtype='string', name='toks')
toks_emb   = layers.Embedding(input_dim = ntoks, output_dim = 32, input_length= maxlen)(toks_inp) ## for small testing data use GLOVE
toks_enc   = layers.LSTM(32)(toks_emb)

pos_inp    = Input(shape=(maxlen,), dtype='string', name='pos')
pos_emb    = layers.Embedding(input_dim = npos, output_dim = 32, input_length= maxlen)(pos_inp)   ## for small testing data use GLOVE
pos_enc    = layers.LSTM(32)(pos_emb)
```

> ntoks:440 | npos:43 | ndep:43 | nrel:22 | maxlen:15

```
### Model
concat     = layers.concatenate([toks_enc, pos_enc], axis=-1)
answers    = layers.Dense(nrel,activation='softmax')(concat)
model      = Model([toks_inp, pos_inp], answers)
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',loss='categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['acc'])

model.fit({'toks': toks_pad, 'pos': pos_pad}, answers, epochs=5, batch_size=10)
```

> ValueError: When feeding symbolic tensors to a model, we expect the
>   tensors to have a static batch size. Got tensor with shape: (None, 22)

Comment: You only feed data to the input of model and don't feed data to `answer`.